# Generate Unique User Identification Number in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, function, authentication, uniqueidentifier

My website is a WordPress website.

My Business Logic involves *Referral*--- where I expect people to refer other people to buy from me, then I offer 15% of the deal to the person who referred the client to me.

To get this Logic to work, I need to generate a **Unique Identification Number**  for each person who registers on my website.

Sadly, WordPress doesn't have this feature natively. And there's no plugin in the entire WordPress Ecosystem that perform this functionality.

This problem has been raised in Stack Exchange in about 10 Years ago, as can be seen here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65738/create-unique-id-for-user

Unfortunately, it has not been solved.

Can anyone Please help me with a PHP Code snippet that can work inside WordPress, so that I can use it to generate a **Unique Identification Number**  for each person who registers on my WordPress website?

2.)When the Unique ID of each member is generated, can you also help me with Code that can help me display it on the User's Profile Page?

Regards.